# Python | JSONPath-ng: filter and values extraction problems

Tags: python, jsonpath

my previous question I though it's good enough to go through loops in json file, then I went for JSONPath and I really like my life since then. But I've new difficulty with adapting the new class;
given this JSON File

```
"8079831875819121": {
            "ID": 8079831875819121,
            "NameKey": "BO_PEEP_UNIT_NAME",
            "UnitStats": {
                "Offense": 42,
                "Defense": 25,
                "Health": 360,
                "Recovery": 72,
                "CritChance": 0.05,
                "CritPower": 1.5,
                "AttackSpeed": 0.23,
                "Speed": 90,
                "Potency": 0.0,
                "Tenacity": 0.05,
                "Accuracy": 0.0,
                "Evasion": 0.0
            },
            "StatProgressionTable": 5620081477795267,
               "Icon": "icons_units_bo_peep/portrait_bo_peep",
            "Obtainable": true,
            "Abilities": [
                {
                    "NameKey": "BO_PEEP_ABILBASIC_NAME",
                    "Icon": "icons_units_bo_peep/bo_peep_basic",
                    "Activated": true,
                    "CastArea": 0,
                    "AbilityType": 1,
                    "Levels": [
                        {
                            "ManaCost": 0,
                            "TargetSelf": false,
                            "TargetAlly": false,
                            "TargetEnemy": true,
                            "Recipe": null,
                            "Requirements": {
                                "Level": 0,
                                "GearTier": 1
                            },
                            "Description": "BOPEEP_BASIC_DESC_01",
                            "UpgradeDescription": "ABILPREVIEWUPGRADE_GEN_ABILITY_UNLOCK",
                            "UpgradeIcon": "icons_ability_upgrade/abilityupgrade_specialfx_3",
                            "IgnoreBuildings": false,
                            "PreviewUpgradeVars": [],
                            "InitialMana": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "ManaCost": 0,
                            "TargetSelf": false,
                            "TargetAlly": false,
                            "TargetEnemy": true,
                            "Recipe": {
                                "Ingredients": [
                                    {
                                        "ItemID": 133,
                                        "Count": 50
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "ItemID": 13,
                                        "Count": 5000
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "Requirements": {
                                "Level": 0,
                                "GearTier": 3
                            },
                            "Description": "BOPEEP_BASIC_DESC_02",
                            "UpgradeDescription": "BOPEEP_BASIC_ABILPREVIEWUPGRADE_01",
                            "UpgradeIcon": "icons_ability_upgrade/abilityupgrade_chance_2",
                            "IgnoreBuildings": false,
                            "PreviewUpgradeVars": [
                                0.5,
                                2.0
                            ],
                            "InitialMana": 0
                        },
                        {
```

That short version I dropped some instances and kept my main needs.
That data object is over one toon, I run through loop over each ID in path `units.*.*`
I need to translate each ability upgrade as a row for a table that contains some varying and some consistent data.
It needs to be like that:
toon_id | ability_id | ability_name | ability_type | target |
that data remains the same and the changing data is:
gear_req | req2 | req3 | req4 | req5

the reqs might be null or incomplete, so I need to fix the Length of the row before appending to a greater table.

I might need more data but as for typing those letters that what I need.

My main problems:

1. I can't find enough good learning materials or finding poor documentaries and examples over jsonpath-ng methods and abstraction. I care to understand more.
2. I'm not really understanding the syntax for the parsing. I find myself struggling to know when It's jpath.key/all(?) or jpath[key/all]
3. I'm failing for fixing the syntax for filter clauses(where?)

If you survived all this please share some wisdom, materials you remember for being great to follow, or advice.

Thanks in advance.

I'm attaching my code, I'd love to receive all kind of comments and critics for improving myself :)

```
total = []
info = []
id_path = 'units.*.ID'
for match in parse(id_path).find(data):
    curr_id = match.value
    info.append(curr_id)
    abil_id_path = f"units.'{curr_id}'.Abilities[*].ID | NameKey | AbilityType"
    first_data = []
    first_data.append(curr_id)
    for match in parse(abil_id_path).find(data):
        path = str(match.path)
        info.append(match.value)
        first_data.append(match.value)
        if len(info) == 4: break
    #abil_levels = f"units.'{curr_id}'.Abilities[*]"
    abil_level_targets = f"units.'{curr_id}'.Abilities[*].Levels[*].'targetSelf'| 'TargetEnemy'| 'TargetAlly' | Requirements | Recipe"
    for match in parse(abil_level_targets).find(data):
        path = str(match.path)
        if match.value == True: 
            info.append(path)
            first_data.append(path)
        if path == 'Requirements': info.append(match.value['GearTier'])
        if path == 'Recipe':
            if match.value is not None:
                for key in match.value['Ingredients']:
                    for ing in key:
                        if ing == 'ItemID': 
                            alpha = key[ing] == 133
                            gold = key[ing] == 13
                            beta = key[ing] == 3883066061505188
                            gamma = key[ing] == 6221535176831871
                            delta = key[ing] == 4010306196179359
                        #print(ing, key[ing])
                        if ing == 'Count':    
                            if gold : info.insert(7,key[ing])
                            if alpha: info.insert(6,key[ing])
                            if beta: info.insert(8,key[ing])
                            if gamma: info.insert(9,key[ing])
                            if delta: info.insert(10,key[ing])
                while 6 < len(info) <11:
                    info.append(0)
                    if len(info) == 11: break
            else:
                while 6 <= len(info) <11:
                    info.append(0)
                    if len(info) == 11: 
                        total.append(info)
                        info = []
                        if len(info) < 1:
                            info.insert(0,curr_id)
                            info.insert(1,first_data[1])
                            info.insert(2,first_data[2])
                            info.insert(3,first_data[3])
                            info.insert(4,first_data[4])

        total.append(info)
        info = []
    if len(info) < 1:
        info.insert(0,curr_id)
        info.insert(1,first_data[1])
        info.insert(2,first_data[2])
        info.insert(3,first_data[3])
        info.insert(4,first_data[4])
```

Comment: Documentation from Github [Python JSONPath Syntax](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng#jsonpath-syntax)

Comment: @AkshayG Thank you, but I'v already checked this link.

Comment: The documentation is enough to explain the different syntax. Try using online tool like https://jsonpath.com/ to query the json using jsonpath.

Comment: @AkshayG LOL just now I found it and it's great. thanks again :)